# More than one row UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need UPDATE some column. t1_id belongs table "h" and t2_id is column table "w". The picture shows the values equal to each other, but have different names, i.e. data of "18840263133600217" 
= data of "339910"

[image]

How can I rename all t1_id to name from t2_id? I want to avoid the error "subquery in the expression returned more than one row"..

```
 update h set h_user_id = 
(select distinct w.h_user_id
from h inner join w 
on h.h_ip = w.h_ip
where "some condition")
```

Comment: put that update query here. for error subquery return more than one row. use `in` clause

Comment: You need a correlated subquery, i.e. one that references the updated table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use `UPDATE FROM`?

```
 UPDATE h SET h_user_id = w.h_user_id 
     FROM w WHERE h.h_ip = w.h_ip AND "some condition"
```

Comment: I can't use `JOIN` becouse of PostgreSQL syntax [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

Comment: Sorry, missed the `postgresql` tag. Updated the answer. `UPDATE FROM` should work, but it depends on your db schema. Can you try?